# Pip error (cannot import name 'main' from 'pip') after upgrading to python 3.8 (Debian 9)

Tags: python-3.x, pip, debian, pymc3

I needed to upgrade Python to install a package (PyMC3) requiring a version>3.5.4. I installed python 3.8.3 without any problem (installing prerequisite libraries, getting file from official repo with wget,using make altinstall, etc), but when I checked python version:

```
eric@debian:/$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.9 :: Anaconda, Inc.
eric@debian:~$ python3.8 --version
Python 3.8.3
```

(honestly, i don't remember having installed anaconda in this computer!; according to the pymc3 install error my version was 3.5.4). I tried to fix it up with update-alternatives:

```
eric@debian:~$ update-alternatives --config python3
There are 2 choices for the alternative python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3).

  Selection    Path                              Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/local/bin/python3.8           10        auto mode
  1            /home/eric/anaconda2/bin/python3   2         manual mode
  2            /usr/local/bin/python3.8           10        manual mode
```

But python3 --version continue throwing Python 3.6.9 :: Anaconda, Inc. When I tried to use pip:

```
eric@debian:~$ sudo pip3 pymc3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main' from 'pip' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/__init__.py)
```

After reading related questions, I tried reinstalling python3-pip but it is already the newest version. I tried to uninstall it with `sudo python3 -m pip uninstall pip` but it gave me a bunch of red error lines, `sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip` didn't work either (same ImportError for name 'main'). By the way:

```
eric@debian:~$ which pip3 pip
/usr/bin/pip3
/home/eric/anaconda2/bin/pip
eric@debian:~$ pip --version
pip 19.3.1 from /home/eric/anaconda2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
eric@debian:~$ pip3 --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main' from 'pip' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/__init__.py)
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: After many tries with posts related to this ImportError and PATH environment, I removed Anaconda2 (which was broken) and installed Anaconda3. It works fine, but when I tried `pip3 --version`:

```
bash: /usr/bin/pip3: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

(but it does exist). When I tried to remove pip3 with, for example, `sudo apt remove python3-pip`:

```
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/apt-listchanges: not found
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -lt 10 returned an error code (1)
E: Failure running script /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -lt 10
```

So I have a problem with `apt` and, despite many hours reading and trying, i couldn't find a way to remove, upgrade,nor even reinstall apt.
Anyway, I guess that this question is no longer suitable for stackoverflow. I will try in superuser or something similar.

Comment: thry this `apt install python3-pip`

Comment: Done, but it fails: `"Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (9.0.1-2+deb9u1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 101 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/apt-listchanges: not found
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -lt 10 returned an error code (1)
E: Failure running script /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -lt 10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue, when I was trying to copy a self compiled python build in a docker container to prod machine. I am going to make a guess for the first issue and provide solution for the second:

**Issue 1:**
`ImportError: cannot import name 'main' from 'pip' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/__init__.py)`

Here anaconda installed python3 is taking preference over OS level Python3. Since your `python3` was not in `/usr/bin` but `pip3` was, I am assuming at sometime, python3 was removed from `/usr/bin`. Deducted from update [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5447#issuecomment-398509506)

**Issue 2:**
`bash: /usr/bin/pip3: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Basically what is happening here is shebang is pip3 script is pointing to `/usr/bin/python3` but on your machine python was NOT available there, so it is failing. Since you made python with `altinstall`, even `pip` was renamed to `pip3.8` and using that would have worked fine. Alternately, updating the pip3 script with correct python location might have also helped, but on my compiled python the import is as follows: `from pip._internal.cli.main import main`

Comment: Thanks! The first issue was solved after reinstalling Anaconda. Regarding the second issue, you're right: pip3 was not pointing to python folder. I managed to solve the pip3 problem: `pip3 --version
pip 20.2.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)`
and it has the same import line that you've mentioned. But pip file is identical and it's located on the same folder: `pip --version
pip 20.2.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)`
Is it ok? Or should it be pointing to my python 2.7 (which is at usr/bin)?

Comment: I have come to realize that python version management is a complete nightname, unless .. Anyways to give you my view, run `which pip` or `which pip3`, ideally it should be in the same location as your `which python` or `which python3` or `which python3.8` and the shebang should point to the same location. Any other value and it is liable to break again once you install python or for some reason $PATH changes.

Comment: I will check the shebangs and I will try to fix it (currently both pip and pip3 are pointing to python 3.8, since both are in the same folder (I have a pip in the python (2,7) folder but it is not in use. Now I have an issue related to apt-get (that arose while trying to fix all this mess). I've posted it as a different question (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/597833/problems-with-apt-listchanges-after-python-upgrade-debian). Thanks!